# Best way to read text file into byte array in selected encoding?

Tags: c#, .net

Now i use something like that:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(filename))
```

Any suggestions how to do that better?

And what encoding uses `File.ReadAllBytes(filename)` method?

P.S. I need utf-8 byte arrays to store text files in db

Comment: What do you suppose to be the UTF encoding of a byte?

Comment: Sorry, i mean store text files in selected encoding using byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Best way to read file into byte array in selected encoding?

[Character Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is about storing text in binary form, as sequences of specific bytes for each character. Another way of thinking about it is that the Encoding system is what gives *meaning* to some bytes. Without the context that some bytes represents text, the bytes are just bytes.

Files are just bytes too; And they can be interpreted however you want  your application to interpret them.

When you **decode** bytes you are giving meaning to those bytes according the encoding system used. For text encodings, you start with bytes and end up with characters.
You can't "*decode*" bytes from a file into a byte array. That doesn't give meaning to the bytes or produce any characters.

You *can* decode bytes into strings using a specific encoding though:

```
string allLinesFromFileAsAuto = File.ReadAllText(filename);
string allLinesFromFileAsUTF8 = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
string allLinesFromFileAsASCII = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.ASCII);
```

All three of these methods convert bytes from the same file into strings, but the resulting strings will be different depending on the encoding you use.

> And what encoding uses `File.ReadAllBytes(filename)` method?

`File.ReadAllBytes(filename)` does not use *any* encoding. Files are just bytes. This method pulls all of a file's bytes into a byte array. You still have to decode those bytes into strings after getting that byte array. *But this only works well for plaintext files.*

> I need utf-8 byte arrays to store files in db

Is this because your database uses UTF-8 encoding?
The encoding of a database defines how **text** is stored (*as binary*).
**Binary** data can be stored as-is, byte-for-byte, as "blobs" in most databases, regardless of the encoding.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
Just forgot to say that i am talking about text files.
And i have a case when i need to read files, in unknown encoding so i decide to convert all of them into utf-8.

Comment: What do you mean by "plaintext files"? Don't you have to know the encoding of every text(file) you try to read? Or else you couldn't decode/read it?

Comment: @user2190035, [Plaintext Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_text) are files that *only* contain characters in some kind of encoding. Usually they are ASCII because most older computers supported ASCII in their text editors, and UTF-8 has been designed to be backwards compatible with ASCII such that you can open ASCII encoded text as UTF-8 and get the same characters.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadAllText` will try to infer the encoding of the file and convert it to .NET strings. Your first example will then convert those to UTF-8 bytes no matter what the source encoding was.

Depending on the size of the files, this could be costly to load it all to memory twice. You can do things to read chunks of the source file and convert it that way.

`ReadAllBytes` reads the raw file as a series of bytes, there's no encoding/decoding for that.

**If you are storing non-text files in the database, you should not encode the file as UTF-8.**

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yes, i am using only text file and (Your first example will then convert those to UTF-8 bytes no matter what the source encoding was) is exactly what I need. I couldn't find a better way to do that so ask here.